# Javafx Button size, EmptyBorder, and Read txt File into TextArea

Tags: button, javafx, textarea, border

I am trying to switch to javafx instead of swing but it has been a bit bumpy trying to find methods that do the exact tasks.

1. I am trying to get the buttons width to fill the entire scene and adjusts accordingly when you adjust the scene size.
2. Get a small empty border around text area and buttons.
3. Getting a method that reads a plain text file and replaces the current Text Area (not append).

   ```
   package gui;

   mport javafx.application.Application;
   mport javafx.scene.Scene;
   mport javafx.scene.control.Button;
   mport javafx.stage.Stage;
   mport javafx.scene.layout.*;
   mport javafx.scene.control.TextArea;

   public class Main extends Application{

       @Override
       public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
           primaryStage.setTitle("TextArea Experiment 1");

           TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
           // Which TextArea method would I call to set a plain 
           // text file into the text area ?      
           BorderPane border = new BorderPane();
           border.setCenter(textArea);
           //border.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
           // Is there a method like this in JavaFx ?
           GridPane grid = new GridPane();
           border.setBottom(grid);

           double screensize = border.getMaxWidth();
           Button option1 = new Button("Button 1");
           Button option2 = new Button("Button 2");
           Button option3 = new Button("Button 3");
           // how can I get the buttons to be max scene size and 
           //adjust dynamically to scene dimensions ? 
           option1.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE,Double.MAX_VALUE);
           //option1.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
           System.out.println(screensize);
           grid.add(option1, 0,1);
           grid.add(option2,0,2);
           grid.add(option3,0,3);


           Scene scene = new Scene(border, 200, 100);
           primaryStage.setScene(scene);
           primaryStage.show();

       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
              Application.launch(args);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: You are asking too many questions in one thread. Try asking one question per thread.

Answer (score 0):

first of all I suggest that to take a look at this tutorial: http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/
If you want to build a well structured javafx application you have to make an **`.fxml`** file, a **Controller** class and (some) **model** class(es).

But for those points here are the answers.

1. If you want to set a `Region`'s size you have to use `.setPrefSize(double,double)` method, if you want to set dynamic you have to use for example `myButton.prefSizeProperty().bind(anyRegionYouWantToBindTo.widthProprty())`
2. I don't really understand what you want, I think you would like to use some styling, then you can write a `.css` file then arr it to `textArea`'s `styleClass`.
3. After you get the text from the file instead of using `textArea.appendText(String)` you have to user `textArea.setText(String)`

I think these are the sollutions for your problems but I strongly recommend to read a tutorial about javafx. So have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your question and only ask the question for this answer. You can then ask the other questions on their own thread.

```
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    grid.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);//Make sure the GridPane MaxWidth is set to MAX_VALUE. you can use grid.gridLinesVisibleProperty().set(true); to get an idea of the GRIDPANES current borders

    border.setBottom(grid);
    grid.gridLinesVisibleProperty().set(true);
    Button option1 = new Button("Button 1");
    option1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);//Set button one MaxWidth to MAX_VALUE

    Button option2 = new Button("Button 2");
    option2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);//Set button two MaxWidth to MAX_VALUE

    Button option3 = new Button("Button 3");
    option3.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);//Set button three MaxWidth to MAX_VALUE

    //Add ColumnConstraints and set the width to 100%.
    ColumnConstraints columnConstraint = new ColumnConstraints();
    columnConstraint.setPercentWidth(100);
    grid.getColumnConstraints().add(0, columnConstraint);

    grid.add(option1, 0, 1);
    grid.add(option2, 0, 2);
    grid.add(option3, 0, 3);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I personally suggest [Gluon SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). I personally think it makes things like this easier.